# Laravel Eloquent Query Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

```
$demos = Demo::whereIn('store_id', [1,2,4], function($query){
                    $query->where('status', 1);
        })->paginate(10);
```

I know that this thats not working, But how can I work with this logic..?

> [Select * from 'demos' where store_id in 1,2,4 and status = 1 ]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you need something like this.

```
$demos = Demo::whereIn('store_id', [1, 2, 4])->where('status', 1)->paginate(10);
```

Chained "where" Eloquent methods == "AND" database query conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, it is better not use ORM`ish approach.
They say, old plain SQL is your best friend. So.

```
$data = \DB::select(
  \DB::raw("SELECT * FROM `demos` WHERE `store_id` IN (:id1, :id2, :id3)"), array( ':id1' => 1, ':id2' => 2, ':id3' => 3 )
);
```

Or, if you have unknown count of `store_id` entries, you could:

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, ...); // looks like unknown ammount of entries
$data = \DB::select(
  \DB::raw("SELECT * FROM `demos` WHERE `store_id` IN (".rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($ids)),',').")"), $ids
);
```

Comment: There are time's where it's better to not use an ORM but this is not one of them. Eloquent is perfectly suited for this query. Your second example is much harder to read than the same thing in Eloquent

Comment: Maybe, but with plain SQL approach you always can write down any query you want, without the need to search the documentation for the desired method or function of your favorite ORM.